# Calculating distance between points within grid polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

I'm very new to ArcGIS, and I would like to calculate the average distance between points within a grid for every grid.

How do I implement this?

My data look like this

[image: Example_of_data]

Answer (score 2):

If this is your definition of average point distance, code below should work:

[image]

> (1+2+4+4+3+2)/6

A new field will be added to the grid fc and calculated as average Point distance.

```py
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

#Change the three lines below to match your data
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Geodatabase of folder holding grid and point fc below
grid = 'fishnet_500m' #Name of your grid feature class
points = 'randompoints' #Name of your Point feature class

resultfield = 'meanpointdistance' #New field that will be added to the grid fc and populated with mean point distance

#Intersect grid with points
inter = 'grid_inter_points'
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(in_features=[grid,points], out_feature_class=inter)
fid_grid_field = 'FID_'+grid

#Group points together by fishnet id using defaultdict(list)
allpoints = defaultdict(list)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inter,[fid_grid_field,'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        allpoints[row[0]].append(row[1])

#Calculate average distances between all point combinations per fishnet id and store in a dictionary
d = {}
for k,v in allpoints.iteritems(): #d.items() in py3/ArcGIS Pro
    if len(v)>1:
        pointdistances = [c[0].distanceTo(c[1]) for c in combinations(v,2)]
        d[k] = sum(pointdistances)/len(pointdistances)

#Add new field and calculate as mean point distance
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=grid, field_name=resultfield, field_type='DOUBLE')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(grid,['OID@',resultfield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in d:
            row[1] = d[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]