# Calculating average of nearest neighbour distance between points in grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, vector-grid

As a novice ArcMap user, I would like to calculate the average of the shortest distances between each point contained in a vector grid.

My inputs are two vector layers : a polygon grid and points.

The idea is to have an output similar to the one mentioned in this topic ([Calculating distance between points within grid polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312861/calculating-distance-between-points-within-grid-polygon)) but with a different calculation because here it is a question of calculating the average of the distances of the points to their nearest neighbour, by limiting the calculation to each tile in the grid.

Comment: What is the difference between the calculation that you need and the one in the proposed duplicate?  What happens when you try implementing your calculation?

Comment: The input data is similar and the desired output is also the same, but in my application it involves first determining the nearest neighbour distance for each point and averaging it over all the points on the grid. In the formula here, the distances are averaged indiscriminately.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap. I've edited my question to reflect your comments.